# Jquery find function not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

First of all I want to say that I watched all questions here about this but none of them help me to solve my issue.
I have a textarea that contains an html code and I want to get images in this textarea, In order to do that I used .find() function but unfortunately it didn't worked.

HTML CODE

```
<textarea id='post' style='display:none;'><div dir="ltr" style="text-align: left;">
<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
<a href="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-TGSXnxdOXok/VKG1rrYMx9I/AAAAAAAABGg/eev4GjIry1g/s1600/photo-1416339306562-f3d12fefd36f-1000x400.jpg"><img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-TGSXnxdOXok/VKG1rrYMx9I/AAAAAAAABGg/eev4GjIry1g/s1600/photo-1416339306562-f3d12fefd36f-1000x400.jpg" /></a></div>
<br />Cras sit amet libero eros, in ultricies lorem. Nunc et odio neque. Maecenas vehicula interdum hendrerit. Integer hendrerit orci ullamcorper neque pellentesque feugiat. Aliquam magna metus, fringilla non ultrices id, fringilla eu erat. Phasellus lorem tortor, porttitor volutpat iaculis sed, condimentum ultricies massa. Curabitur ut malesuada elit. Nullam tortor mi, faucibus a laoreet a, ultricies ut est. Etiam erat urna, dapibus vitae sodales eu, sagittis ut nisl. Curabitur vitae tristique felis. Donec consectetur porttitor lectus ac pharetra. Mauris nulla nisi, congue quis eleifend at, dapibus eget augue. Curabitur nunc sem, feugiat sit amet facilisis quis, laoreet id mi.<br />
</div>
</textarea>
```

Jquery CODE

```
var content = $('#post').val();
var img = content.find('img').attr('src');
alert(img);
```

[JsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h0w9mgxe/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Value of a textarea is a string, and you'd first need to convert it into a DOM structure.

To get the DOM structure, you need to wrap the string you have in another jQuery selector:

```
var content = $($('#post').val());
```

It basically does this:

```
var myString = $('#post').val();
var content = $(myString);
```

---

See it in action here:

```js
var content = $($('#post').val());
var img = content.find('img').attr('src');
alert(img);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id='post' style='display:none;'><div dir="ltr" style="text-align: left;">
<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
<a href="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-TGSXnxdOXok/VKG1rrYMx9I/AAAAAAAABGg/eev4GjIry1g/s1600/photo-1416339306562-f3d12fefd36f-1000x400.jpg"><img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-TGSXnxdOXok/VKG1rrYMx9I/AAAAAAAABGg/eev4GjIry1g/s1600/photo-1416339306562-f3d12fefd36f-1000x400.jpg" /></a></div>
<br />Cras sit amet libero eros, in ultricies lorem. Nunc et odio neque. Maecenas vehicula interdum hendrerit. Integer hendrerit orci ullamcorper neque pellentesque feugiat. Aliquam magna metus, fringilla non ultrices id, fringilla eu erat. Phasellus lorem tortor, porttitor volutpat iaculis sed, condimentum ultricies massa. Curabitur ut malesuada elit. Nullam tortor mi, faucibus a laoreet a, ultricies ut est. Etiam erat urna, dapibus vitae sodales eu, sagittis ut nisl. Curabitur vitae tristique felis. Donec consectetur porttitor lectus ac pharetra. Mauris nulla nisi, congue quis eleifend at, dapibus eget augue. Curabitur nunc sem, feugiat sit amet facilisis quis, laoreet id mi.<br />
</div>
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to get jQuery to parse the HTML inside the textarea first. Just wrap `$('#post').val()` in a jQuery object.

```
var content = $($('#post').val());
var img = content.find('img').attr('src');
alert(img);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/0f9tjrs2/